# Datepicker loses binding when changing element ID

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm using the jQuery datepicker on a formset in which we can add and delete forms. When adding a new form I have a `set_fields` function added to the `Form` prototype which attaches datepickers to the new fields and this works fine.

However, when deleting a form, I completely delete the chosen form from the DOM and update the IDs of each other form so that they're numbered consecutively (therefore the backend can expect a given number of consecutively-numbered forms rather than maintaining a 'deleted' list).

The issue I have is that, when I delete a form and the remaining forms have their IDs changed, the bindings for the datepickers stay on the next form, so changing a date in one form will change the value for the field in the next form (and the last form gives the error `Missing instance data for this datepicker`). I've tried calling `set_fields` for the form after I've changed the IDs (therefore calling `datepicker()` again on all the fields for which I've changed the ID) but the bindings still don't change. I've also tried manually cycling through all the elements with attached datepickers and called `datepicker()` on them again, but again nothing changes.

Let me know if you need to see any specific parts of the code.

Comment: it's hard to say without seeing your code, but re-assigning id's to DOM elements doesn't sound like the right approach.  perhaps you want to toggle classes instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you change your id of element, then you must remove 'hasDatepicker' class then reinitialize datepicker with selector.

**Example**:

```js
$(selector).removeClass('hasDatepicker');
$(selector).datepicker({
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding the solution [here](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/trouble-initializing-datepicker-in-dynamically-added-table-rows). The problem was that when fields have datepickers added, the field is given a `hasDatepicker` class. If you then try to reinitialise the datepicker on that field, it will ignore it if the field already has the `hasDatepicker` class. So I just removed that class from each of the elements I wanted to reinitialise, then called my `set_fields` function and it worked!